# nxt-python run two motors simultaneously

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms, nxt-python

I am trying to run two motors connected to Port A and B of Mindstorms NXT simultaneously

```
b=nxt.locator.find()

def rotatewheel():
  mymotor = b.get_motor(nxt.motor.Port.A)
  secondmotor=b.get_motor(nxt.motor.Port.B)
  syncmot=nxt.motor.SynchronizedMotors(mymotor,secondmotor,0)
  syncmot.turn(25,300,timeout=3)
```

However, this did not move the motor and debugging throws the following:

> DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 000600 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060000000701002000000000de17000000000000de170000
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 000601 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060001000701002000000000aaf5ffff00000000aaf5ffff
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:reversed DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send: 000a0001
> DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv: 020a00 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 000a0101 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv: 020a00 DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting
> brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send: 000600
> DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060000000701002000000000de17000000000000de170000
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 000601 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060001000701002000000000aaf5ffff00000000aaf5ffff
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:updating motor information DEBUG:nxt.motor:setting
> brick output state: Mode.REGULATED|ON, RegulationMode.SYNC, 0,
> RunState.RUNNING, 0 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 800400190502002000000000 DEBUG:nxt.motor:setting brick output state:
> Mode.REGULATED|ON, RegulationMode.SYNC, 0, RunState.RUNNING, 0
> DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send: 800401190502002000000000
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:tachocount: tacho: 6110 -2646 DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting
> brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send: 000600
> DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060000190502002000000000de17000000000000de170000
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 000601 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060001190502002000000000aaf5ffff00000000aaf5ffff DEBUG:nxt.motor:not
> advancing: tacho: 6110 -2646 tacho: 6110 -2646 DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting
> brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send: 000600
> DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060000190502002000000000de17000000000000de170000
> DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send:
> 000601 DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:recv:
> 02060001190502002000000000aaf5ffff00000000aaf5ffff DEBUG:nxt.motor:not
> advancing: tacho: 6110 -2646 tacho: 6110 -2646 DEBUG:nxt.motor:getting
> brick output state DEBUG:nxt.backend.usb:send: 000600

and the error message

> nxt.motor.BlockedException: Blocked!

> INFO:nxt.backend.usb:closing USB (Bus 004 Device 010) connection

How do I move the two motors simultaneously?